# Rewriting half of a low-ranking article - is it better to delete it and create a new webpage?

Tags: seo

There's an article on my blog, half of which I'm thinking of rewriting, and this got me thinking. Is it a better idea to delete the article, rewrite the second half, then repost it on a new webpage - or is it better to keep the original webpage and rewrite the second half there?

On one hand, the article has currently fallen in ranking for some of the keywords I wanted, so it might have racked up a bad reputation based on how readers respond to it (% people clicking back onto the SERPs, average visit time etc.) which might be detrimental to the rewritten article on the same page. On the other hand, it does have some links and Facebook likes - and the duplicate content which comes from the first half of the original post might be detrimental for the new webpage.

Any takes on this? Let me know if there's any other information you need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You articulated the scenario very well. Personally, I would keep the article and update it. The reason is to preserve a few things that will pay off in the end; the links, the likes, and the age of the article. Google will see that you updated the article and you will get some momentum from that. It will take a long time before the article performs where it should, but in the end, I think you will be better off. A new article will not be seen as duplicate if the old one is removed. Google is very forgiving in these cases mostly because it takes a while to figure things out, and by the time they do, "Oh! It's fixed." A new article may perform well enough, but it is new, does not have links, does not have likes, and such and so the process would have to start again.